# User input into 2d multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console-application

Simple console app that takes user input into a multidimensional array as students, and scores. Having trouble getting the entered scores from the loop, into the array. Do I need a nested loop?

```
     Console.WriteLine("How many students will you be grading?");
            string totalStudents = Console.ReadLine();
            int studentSum = Convert.ToInt32(totalStudents);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine("How many test scores will you enter for each student?");
            string totalScores = Console.ReadLine();
            int scoreSum = Convert.ToInt32(totalScores);

            int[,] studentScores = new int[studentSum, scoreSum];
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);


        for (int scoreIndex = 0; scoreIndex < scoreSum; scoreIndex++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter score");
            var score = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            int parsedScore = 0;
            success = int.TryParse(score, out parsedScore);

            studentScores[scoreSum] = parsedScore;

        }
```

Comment: I've read your question several times and I still have no idea what you're asking or what the issue is.

Comment: since studentScores is a 2d array, you need to have 2 for loops (nested for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need another loop around like

```
    for (int scoreIndex = 0; scoreIndex < studentSum; scoreIndex++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<studentSum; j++) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter score");
        var score = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        int parsedScore = 0;
        success = int.TryParse(score, out parsedScore);

        studentScores[scoreIndex,j] = parsedScore;
      }
    }
```